# 時間入力フォームに現在時刻を自動入力したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

#### 前提・実現したいこと

jQueryで実装しています。
開始時間と終了時間の入力をさせ、その差分によって金額を表示するフォームを作成しています。
この時間入力フォームに「現在時刻」というボタンを配置し、そこを押せば自動的に現在時刻が入力される、というものを作りたいです。
時間形式は「11:20」のようにしてます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

現在時間の時間と分をそれぞれ取得できているのですが、フォームにうまく反映されません。

#### 該当のソースコード

```html
%form
  .time
  %dl
    %dt 開始時間
    %dd
      %input{:autofocus => "true", :max => "23:00", :min => "11:00", :name => "start_time", :required => "", :type => "time", :value => "11:00"}/
      %button.nowtime 現在時間
    %dt 終了時間
    %dd
      %input{:name => "last_time", :required => "", :type => "time", :value => "11:00"}/
      %button.nowtime 現在時間
```

```js
  $('.nowtime').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(e.currentTarget).parents('form');
    var Hour = new Date().getHours();
    var Min = new Date().getMinutes();
    $form.find('input[name="start_time"]').val(Hour+':'+Min);
    $form.find('input[name="last_time"]').val(Hour+':'+Min);
  })
```

#### 試したこと

ここには文字を代入するのではなく、時間形式にして代入するのでは？と仮説をし、調べました。
innerHTMLプロパティをつかうのかな、と思ったのですが、結局表示されませんでした。
初心者です。すみませんがどなたかご回答お願いします。

Comment: Chrome で試すと DevTools のコンソールに何か警告が出ませんか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
コンソールを確認したところ、現在時刻が1桁のときに代入できないとありました！
そこで修正してみたところ、うまくいきました！
これからコンソールちゃんと確認します。ありがとうございました！！

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/263018